# MD5 Hash function python

Tags: python, hash, md5

I'm trying to write a MD5 hash function for experimentation purposes fallowing the pseudocode on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Pseudocode). Here is my code:

```
s = [
    7, 12, 17, 22,  7, 12, 17, 22,  7, 12, 17, 22,  7, 12, 17, 22,
    5,  9, 14, 20,  5,  9, 14, 20,  5,  9, 14, 20,  5,  9, 14, 20,
    4, 11, 16, 23,  4, 11, 16, 23,  4, 11, 16, 23,  4, 11, 16, 23,
    6, 10, 15, 21,  6, 10, 15, 21,  6, 10, 15, 21,  6, 10, 15, 21,
]

K = [
    0xd76aa478, 0xe8c7b756, 0x242070db, 0xc1bdceee,
    0xf57c0faf, 0x4787c62a, 0xa8304613, 0xfd469501,
    0x698098d8, 0x8b44f7af, 0xffff5bb1, 0x895cd7be,
    0x6b901122, 0xfd987193, 0xa679438e, 0x49b40821,
    0xf61e2562, 0xc040b340, 0x265e5a51, 0xe9b6c7aa,
    0xd62f105d, 0x02441453, 0xd8a1e681, 0xe7d3fbc8,
    0x21e1cde6, 0xc33707d6, 0xf4d50d87, 0x455a14ed,
    0xa9e3e905, 0xfcefa3f8, 0x676f02d9, 0x8d2a4c8a,
    0xfffa3942, 0x8771f681, 0x6d9d6122, 0xfde5380c,
    0xa4beea44, 0x4bdecfa9, 0xf6bb4b60, 0xbebfbc70,
    0x289b7ec6, 0xeaa127fa, 0xd4ef3085, 0x04881d05,
    0xd9d4d039, 0xe6db99e5, 0x1fa27cf8, 0xc4ac5665,
    0xf4292244, 0x432aff97, 0xab9423a7, 0xfc93a039,
    0x655b59c3, 0x8f0ccc92, 0xffeff47d, 0x85845dd1,
    0x6fa87e4f, 0xfe2ce6e0, 0xa3014314, 0x4e0811a1,
    0xf7537e82, 0xbd3af235, 0x2ad7d2bb, 0xeb86d391
]

def hash(message):
    if isinstance(message, str):
        message = message.encode('utf-8')
    message = int.from_bytes(message, 'little')

    # Initialize variables:
    a0 = 0x67452301  # A
    b0 = 0xefcdab89  # B
    c0 = 0x98badcfe  # C
    d0 = 0x10325476  # D

    original_length = message.bit_length()

    # Pre-processing: add a single 1 bit
    message = (message << 1) + 1

    # Pre-processing: padding with zeros.
    # TODO: no need for a while loop, just shift the right number of bits
    while message.bit_length() % 512 != 448:
        message = message << 1
    # Add original length of message
    message = (message << 64) + (original_length % pow(2, 64))

    while message:
        # 512 bit chunk
        chunk = message & (pow(2, 512) - 1)
        message = message >> 512

        # Split the chunk into 16 32-bit words
        M = []
        while chunk:
            M.append(chunk & (pow(2, 32) - 1))
            chunk = chunk >> 32

        # Initialize hash value for this chunk
        A = a0
        B = b0
        C = c0
        D = d0

        for i in range(64):
            if i < 16:
                F = (B & C) | (bit_not(B) & D)
                g = i
            elif i < 32:
                F = (D & B) | (bit_not(D) & C)
                g = (5*i + 1) % 16
            elif i < 48:
                F = (B ^ C ^ D)
                g = (3*i + 5) % 16
            else:
                F = C ^ (B | bit_not(D))
                g = (7*i) % 16

            dTemp = D
            D = C
            C = B
            B = leftrotate((A + F + K[i] + M[g]), s[i])
            A = dTemp

        a0 = A
        b0 = B
        c0 = C
        d0 = D

    ret = (a0 << (32*3)) + (b0 << (32*2)) + (c0 << 32) + d0
    return ret.to_bytes(16, 'little').hex()

def bit_not(x):
    """Invert all bits in x (as opposed to ~ which will also make the number nagative)"""
    return pow(2, 32) - 1 - x

def leftrotate(x, c):
    """Rotate bits left by c bits"""
    return (x << c) & (pow(2, 32)-1) | (x >> (32-c))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    print(hash(sys.stdin.read()))
```

It produces hashes, but when compared to `hashlib.md5` it doesn't produce the same values. I've tried tweaking various things but I can't get the hashes to line up. As far as I can tell it's the same the code on Wikipedia (it's possible Wikipedia)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure why your code gives wrong values. There _might_ be endian problems somewhere, and I think there are a few places that need the values to be restricted to 32 bit, using eg `& 0xffffffff`. FWIW, there's a Python implementation of MD5 [here](http://starship.python.net/crew/gherman/md5py.html) that appears to work. The code's rather ancient, but it runs ok on Python 2.6.